# why I am getting undefined value in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me why I am getting undefined value .When I click on chart ? I make one bar chart and try to get it value .In other words try to get selected item and it’s value .
In give fiddle it gives correct value 
http://jsfiddle.net/b4n9z19v/
But when I make directive and try to get it value it is giving me undefined why ?
here is code
http://plnkr.co/edit/FtDfeyd6fjHL3RNwzyCn?p=preview

```
$scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
                     $element.bind('click', function (event) {
                // do your code
                alert( $scope.chartData.chart.type);
                alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
            });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is because `this` is pointing to something else than inside the highcharts

Comment: yes ..you are correct so what is solution

Comment: use function prototype called 'bind' to set this

Comment: please prodive plunker

Comment: How are you populating chart data? Which variable you're using for  populating graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add click event to the chart object, in a similar way as you did for data.json? Like this:

```
            $scope.chartData.plotOptions.series.point.events.click = function (event) {
                // do your code
                alert( $scope.chartData.chart.type);
                alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
            };
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WA4TcDuoer3ix08T15QM?p=preview